# R survey package: compare weighted prevalence with literature result

Tags: r, statistical-significance, survey, survey-weights, prevalence

I have a large dataset (>3000 cases) with results of serological tests. Based on these results i want to calculate the weighted prevalence of the disease. The data is categorical (0 = disease absent; 1 = disease present). 12 cases have the disease. After weighting by inverse selection probability based on the population data, i come to a weighted prevalence of +/- 0.25% (95% CI 0.10% - 0.45%).

Now i want to compare this result with a reported historical prevalence. Unfortunately, there is very little information about the older result and it is impossible to reconstruct the weighting used then. The publication reports a weighted prevalence of 0.7% (95% CI 0.5 - 0.8) with 13/1830 cases being positive.

Based on the fact that the CI do not overlap i know they are statistically significant but what test can i use to compare the results and generate a p-value? I suppose the survey design of my dataset should be taken into account, and the low number of events should be considered.